# Unique Customers with Duplicate Order Numbers

Tags: ms-access-2007

It seems a dataset I've been given has multiple customer IDs with the same Order Numbers.  How would I go about identifying those customer who have been effected?

I did try the usual but then realised some Order Numbers are duplicated but with the same Cus ID?

```
SELECT Cus ID, Ord Num, COUNT(*) 
FROM OUTPUT
GROUP BY Cus ID, Order Num, Amount
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the orders using a subquery:

```
  SELECT OrdNum, COUNT(DISTINCT CustId) 
  FROM OUTPUT
  GROUP BY OrdNum
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CustId) > 1
```

You can get the details by joining the information back in:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM (SELECT OrdNum, COUNT(DISTINCT CustId) 
      FROM OUTPUT
      GROUP BY OrdNum
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CustId) > 1
     ) as oc INNER JOIN
     OUTPUT as o
     on oc.OrdNum = o.OrdNum
```

EDIT:

In Access, you can do:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM (SELECT OrdNum
      FROM OUTPUT
      GROUP BY OrdNum
      HAVING MIN(CustId) <> MAX(CustId)
     ) as oc INNER JOIN
     OUTPUT as o
     on oc.OrdNum = o.OrdNum;
```

Comment: I thought count(distinct) was not available in access?

Comment: @AHughes . . . I think you are right.  I do forget all the limitations of Access. I added another solution.